# Regex : To exclude white spaces in a line which is between 2 numbers (.net)

Tags: .net

I have a statement (in a line) and I want to extract the numbers only and not the dots and blank spaces. It would be of great help if someone can help me out.  Below is the example statement (single line string):

BIC: XXXXXXXX                      Naam: MR. YYYYY INZ. ABCIRR. NE     Abcdefghijlk: ABCDE: 57.10.70.13   2 THE NEXPRK BV IF TE VERREKENEN    SALDO

Output I require is : 571070132

What I have achieved now is to pull in the digits alone (without 2), below is the regex :
(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2})
Unable to go ahead with this.  Please help

Answer (score 1):

You do not need regex for something like this - LINQ expression `str.Where(char.IsDigit)` will work better:

```
var str = "BIC: XXXXXXXX Naam: MR. YYYYY INZ. ABCIRR. NE Abcdefghijlk: ABCDE: 57.10.70.13 2 THE NEXPRK BV IF TE VERREKENEN SALDO";
var res = new String(str.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", res);
```

This [produces](http://ideone.com/2reJ1h) the following output:

```
'571070132'
```

The problem with applying regex to this is that the match would be produced in multiple groups, so your code would need to iterate them in order to build the final output. LINQ provides a more direct approach that is also easier to read.

Comment: i think regex is the way to go. your method is way more complex

Comment: @jurik Show me how you could do it with regex, including the part where you strip out the dots and spaces. The code to beat is included above, but here it is one more time: `str.Where(char.IsDigit)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i know, but the question was about how to do it with regular expressions, so i answered the question. If it was asked how to do it with LINQ, then you are absolutely right

Comment: @alexandre, that all depends on what you are used to. a LINQ or Lambda expression can be just as hard to read imho. But it is all in the eye of the beholder. Again, the question was about regex not linq

Comment: @jurik ["Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight update: he HAS to use a regex in third party tool. But you are right about your statement in most cases tho

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there

this should work

\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2} \d

after this you can strip out the . and ' ' (space) with replace option if they remain.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But, I have to use regex to solve this.  I tried \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2} \d - but, doesn't seem to work.  Using regex I need the output 571070132

Comment: can you tell me what tooling you are using. .net or bash or pearl or whatever. I think it can be done, but not solely with regex matching. The . and space have to be skipped somehow before or after or with regex groups.

Comment: I am using a .net based tool.  Meaning I do not have direct access to .net and cannot edit any of the queries.  I'm just exposed to the regex and hence this issue.  Apart from regex, I do not have any control on the flow of the data till it hits database.  Can anything be done through regex alone?  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I understand completely. I will have another go at it tomorrow. (or after the match. regex is a very strong tool of which i have only harnessed a mere portion of it's power ;))

Comment: so far i hit a brick if you cannot use regex.replace also. I think you should try to pre or post replace the . and whitespaces somehow

Comment: Overwhelmed with the response so far.
Currently \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2} would pull me 57107013 (excluding the dot) - would leave me to deal with 3 blank spaces followed by 2.
I'm having bad time thinking over this again and again, may be I need some rest today to come up with anything else.  I'd wait for your response tomorrow.  w.r.t. match - hope best team wins (although i favour Holland)